# How to set view between activity views and tablayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have a TabLayout. In the MainActivity where I set the TabLayout I also have three buttons and a banner on bottom (so those buttons and banner are on front of the the tablayout). What I want to do is place an ImageView exactly between the button/banner and the tab. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Here is a picture of the layout, I want the view exactly in center between buttons and layout.

Code main_activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.tomhogenkamp.NeonDiscoLight.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_above="@id/adView"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="settings"
                android:id="@+id/setting"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="start"
                android:id="@+id/start"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="rate"
                android:id="@+id/rate"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and code for fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewStrobe"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewStroboscope"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post some code. Instead of having everyone imagine how you layout looks like

Comment: I added a picture so it is more clear what I mean